Prove that $\cosh x = \dfrac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{C}(\cos 2x)$
Let $x$ be a variable. Prove that $\cosh x = \dfrac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{C}(\cos 2x)$.

Ideas.
(1) $\mathbb{C}(\cos 2x) = \mathbb{C}(2cos^{2}(x)-1)= \mathbb{C}(2\cos^{2} x) = \mathbb{C}(e^{ix}+e^{-2ix})$.
(2) $\cosh x$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{C}(\cos 2x)$ if and only if  $\dfrac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{C}(e^{ix}+e^{-2ix})$ if and only if $e^{x}+e^{-x}$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{C}(e^{ix}+e^{-2ix})$.
(3) If $e^{x}+e^{-x}$ and $e^{ix}+e^{-2ix}$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$, then  $\cosh x$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{C}(\cos 2x)$.


As in your previous question: please don't do use random tags that don't fit.

What is $x$? Is it a number with some properties, or do you understand $\cos x$ as a function?

@user8268 Most likely neither.  I would assume $\cos x \in \mathbb{C}[[x]]$.  (It can be viewed as the function if needed)

If it's not transcendental, it satisfies a polynomial equation
$\sum_{j=0}^n c_j(x) y^j = 0$ with coefficients $c_j$, not all identically $0$, in $\mathbb C[\cos(2x)]$.  Let's say $c_n(t) \ne 0$, $t \in \mathbb R$.
But the $c_j$ are periodic with period $\pi$, so $\cosh(t + n \pi)$ for integers $n$ all satisfy the same polynomial of degree $n$.  That's impossible because the values of $\cosh$ on $\mathbb R$ are all distinct except for the symmetry $\cosh(-x) = \cosh(x)$, and a polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots.
